# modified footcite worked 2016 - what changed since then?

Tags: biblatex

I made a big effort back in 2016 to get all my needed settings for creating a document matching certain requirements. Now I re-used my setup to create a new document. There were some smaller fixes I had to implement, some deprecated arguments and stuff like that, nothing really big. It seems like everything was working fine.

But one thing gives me trouble. I use footcite and in the output I need brackets around the year. My old setup gets just ignored (it worked definately in 2016). The output is like I expect it to be, but the brackets around the year are missing. What has changed since then?

```
% Klammern um das Jahr in der Fußnote
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{% 
  \iffieldundef{labelyear} 
    {} 
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{% 
       \mkbibparens{% 
         \printfield{labelyear}% 
         \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```

My setup of biblatex is the following

```
\usepackage[
defernumbers=true,
backend=biber,
minnames=1,
maxnames=1,
ibidtracker=context,
bibstyle=numeric,
citestyle=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
url=false, 
isbn=false,
hyperref=true,
urldate=comp,   
dateabbrev=false,
sortlocale=de]{biblatex}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One change that is certainly relevant for you is that the bibmacro `cite:labelyear+extrayear` was renamed to `cite:labeldate+extradate` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/189d90db9dbe94dd08f47261e79df09e2a37c66a, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/320f114d493ca7fa310c559c3a48b5912282fa22). A list of relevant recent name changes can be found at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Name-Changes.

A few other things with the date handling have changed as well so that a modernised version of the code would probably read

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citelabeldate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printtext[citelabeldate]{\printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

---

A similar effect could be obtained using one of the `biblatex-ext` styles and

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
```

---

I should add that mixing `bibstyle=numeric,` and `citestyle=authoryear,` will lead to superfluous numbers in the bibliography that have nothing to do with any other numbering in the document (the citations do *not* use those numbers, they are author-year).

The option `hyperref=true,` is usually not better than the default `hyperref=auto,`. The two options only differ in that `true` emits a warning if the `hyperref` package is not loaded. With both options links will be added if and only if the `hyperref` package is loaded. Neither setting loads the package `hyperref` automatically.

It should rarely be required to set `sortlocale=de`, the `sortlocale` will automatically be inferred from the document language settings.

Comment: I copied your five lines into my document, replaced my code and it works! Perfect and a very big thank you!

I didn't notice any superfluous numbers in the bibliography, all looks fine.

The hyperref arguments is just my preferred way. After two years I forget what "auto" means, "true" remains clear after any period of time.

The sortlocale... I can't remember why I did it, but it's not harmful...