# How to make footcite look like textcite with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, footcite

`\footcite` produces a formatted citation that looks like `\cite` rather than `\textcite`. How can I make `\footcite` look like `\textcite` with biblatex?

I have found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458155/36836 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426113/36836 but this only adds brackets around the year (not the page number). (It also only works with the `ext-authoryear-icomp`, but I am fine with using it if it has no other detrimental side effects.)

Same for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501320/36836. (However, the non-`ext-authoryear-icomp` variant also adds strange additional square brackets around the year of my `\textcite`s. Maybe some interaction with another modification I am using in my document. But I am not sure.)

Here is the actual and wanted result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,        
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  journaltitle = {A Journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  location = {There},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Current result \autocite[23]{A01}.

Wanted result.\footnote{\textcite[23]{B02}.}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authoryear-icomp`'s `\textcite` definition is among the most complex citation commands defined by standard `biblatex`. It uses a two-pass structure to get the `-comp` bit of the format right. That means that it is actually defined in terms of two citation commands: one that does the preprocessing and a second internal command that does the actual formatting.

Fortunately, it is possible to transplant that setup from `\textcite` to `\footcite` and `\smartcite` (which is what `\autocite` is in your setup).

If you want to move the position of the prenote, you need to modify the `textcite` bibmacro so that it doesn't print the prenote and print the prenote in the precode of the cite commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% same as 'textcite' but does not print the prenote
\newbibmacro*{foottextcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extradate}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}


% \footcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{foottextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@footcite}{footcite}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@footcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\cbx@footcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@footcites]{\footcite}{}

% \footcitetext
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{foottextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@footcitetext}{footcite}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@footcitetext]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@footcitetexts}[\mkbibfootnotetext]{\cbx@footcitetext}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcitetexts}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@footcitetexts]{\footcitetext}{}

% \smartcite (=\autocite in your setup)
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{foottextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@smartcite}{smartcite}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@smartcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@smartcites}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]{\cbx@smartcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@smartcites]{\smartcite}{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Current result \autocite[See][380]{sigfridsson}.

Wanted result.\autocites[24-26]{nussbaum}[13]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 See Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, p. 380).//2 Nussbaum (1978, pp. 24–26) and Geer (1985, p. 13).]

Comment: Awesome. Seems to work in principle. Now, I am trying to integrate it into my document. I hope it comes out as I would have expected.

Comment: Okay, I think it worked as it was to be expected. Thanks. Unfortunately, I made a mistake when thinking about the effects. For example, `\autocite[See ][380]{sigfridsson}` normally results in `See Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 380.` But with `\textcite` it creates `Sigfridsson and Ryde (See 1998, p. 380).` I wasn't aware that `\textcite` acts in that way. What I need is actually `See Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, p. 380).`.

Comment: @Daniel All possible, the code doesn't get shorter, though. See the edit, please.

Comment: As long as it works. And it seems to work fabulously. Thanks for your help!