# What is the location of the biblatex citation style files?

Tags: biblatex

I am basically ignorant about `biblatex` but many have recommended it to me. I am trying to do something too tricky or too stupid ([How to make footcite look like textcite with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539227/36836)). Since I got no feedback on my first attempt, maybe I could check the definition of the `\textcite` command and learn from it in order to replace the `\autocite` command accordingly. My problem with this step is that I do not even find the citation commands on my machine. If I understood correctly, these are `.cbx` files. Does any one know where to find them on a macOS running TeX Live?

Comment: I slightly edited the title and the tags to make the question less macOS-centric, since the approach is the same for all OSes and big TeX distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex`'s citation commands are usually defined in `<style>.cbx`, the bibliography setup in `<style>.bbx`.

Run `kpsewhich authoryear-icomp.cbx` on the command line to find the location of `authoryear-icomp.cbx` on your machine.  You can also find it the current release version of the file online on GitHub https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-icomp.cbx or on CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/cbx/authoryear-icomp.cbx.

When you are manipulating bibliography and citation styles you probably also want to have

- [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) and
- [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)

open, since they contain many basic definitions.

`.bbx` and `.cbx` files can load other `.bbx` files with `\RequireBibliographyStyle{<bibstyle>}` and `.cbx` files with `\RequireCitationStyle{<citestyle>}`, so in some cases you may have to chase the definitions in different files.

Most author- and user-facing `biblatex` core commands are defined in [`biblatex.sty`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty), but it should usually not be necessary to look up their definition there. The documentation is more helpful for those commands.

Comment: Be aware that the definition of `\textcite` in `authoryear-icomp` is probably the second most complex citation command in all of standard `biblatex`: It uses a two-pass structure that processes each citation key twice to get the `comp` bit right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. That makes me worried because I use just that style. I guess I am trying to take a sledge hammer to crack the nut. All I actually want is brackets around the year number including the page number as in `Knuth (2000, 34)`. Currently it shows `Knuth 2000, 34`. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: @Daniel Give me a few minutes. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Comment: @moewe: What is the meaning of `.bbx` and `.cbx` and `.lbx`?

Comment: @Balaji `.bbx` files contain bibliography style definitions, `.cbx` files contain citation style definitions and `.lbx` contain localisation/language-dependent definitions. Usually one `biblatex` style will consist of one `.bbx` and one `.cbx` style. Depending on how interwoven bibliography and citation output are, it is not always easy to decide or even clear if a definition belongs into the `.bbx` or `.cbx` file.