# Customize biblatex citation style

Tags: biblatex

for citations I normally use 'authortitle-icomp' style. Now I need for a work a little bit more complex styles and I don't know how to start.

For the first reference of a title in a footnote I need:

> First name Name, Title. Subtitle (if given), Place and Year (if given), Page (if given)

Like:
[image: First reference]

For every further reference of the title I have to use a short version:

> Name, Title, Page (if given)

Like:
[image: Short title]

What I have:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authortitle-icomp,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
isbn=false,
url=false, 
doi=false,
eprint=false,
dashed=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers={et al.},}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{Art.: \textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection,article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}
        \setunit*{\addspace}
        \usebibmacro{date}}
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\setunit{\addspace}\printdate}
```

I don't expect a solution for this problem, but maybe you can provide some links for tutorials or documentations. I am still a beginner in LaTeX and especially in BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style you describe looks like one of the `verbose` family would be a good fit. I chose `verbose-ibid` to preserve the "ibidem" capabilities of `authoryear-icomp`. You can find a list of all standard styles in §3.3 *Standard Styles* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). If your version of `biblatex` is up to date, that section will link to style examples in the right margin. (You can find the style examples on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) if there is no link in the margins).

With `verbose-inote` the footnote citations already have the desired general setup: The first citation is long (pretty much the same as the bibliography entry), subsequent citations only mention author and title.

I have slightly modernised the remaining code from your MWE (it should be possible to tell what line does what by comparing with your previous code and possibly searching for the commands in the documentation, but I'll be happy to answer any questions you might have about that in the comments). I also decided to use `ext-verbose-ibid` from my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) as basis instead of the standard `verbose-ibid`, because that makes it easier to change a few things (here mainly the space between `location` and `date`).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,
  isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, eprint=false,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\textsc}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers={et al\adddot},}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{Art\addot\addcolon\space\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection,article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\letbibmacro{publisher+location+date}{location+date}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{werbick,
  author    = {Jürgen Werbick},
  title     = {Gott verbindlich},
  subtitle  = {Eine theologische Gotteslehre},
  date      = {2007},
  publisher = {Herder},
  location  = {Freiburg},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[591]{werbick}
ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor\autocite[592]{werbick}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jürgen Werbick, Gott verbindlich. Eine theologische Gotteslehre, Freiburg 2007, 591.// Werbick, Gott verbindlich, 592.]

---

It's a long-standing issue that there are no intermediate `biblatex` tutorials for style authors (or those interested in more advanced style modifications). There are some hints at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) and some of the resources listed in [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) have sections about style modifications (for example https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial/releases), but there is no full-on tutorial for style matters.

In 2008 Dominik Waßenhoven wrote a (German) two-part article in *Die TeXnische Komödie* about his  `biblatex` style (https://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2008_2.pdf, https://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2008_4.pdf). That is pretty much the only resource I know of that deals with more advanced `biblatex` stuff in article/tutorial form. Note that the articles are more than 10 years old now, many details have changed since then. The overall approach is still the same, but I expect that there will be new, more elegant interfaces for a few things.

You will find lots of questions about all sorts of shenanigans with `biblatex` on this site and elsewhere on the web.

At some point in your style writing process it may be useful to look at the source code to see how things are done. (See [What is the location of the citation command files on macOS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864) for hints about that.)

Comment: Thank you for your code, example and the hint to the documentation.

Comment: One additional question: For the bibliography I need some other format options. Where in the documentation of biblatex do I have to look to find options like adding dot after all authors and title or move the word publisher in brackets after all publishers?

I don't want this changes for the citations, just in the bibliography.

Comment: @BjörnEngel Many things are not controlled by simple options or single commands. Things like moving fields and some changes in punctuation have to be achieved by redefining bibmacros and drivers. But the exact implementations of the bibdrivers and bibmacros are not documented, you have to find out about them by looking at the code. If you don't manage to find the answer by looking at the source code, don't hesitate to ask a new question.