# Remove dots after year biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to remove the dots after year. And also volume should be bold. How to do this?

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  dashed=false,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{ipab730bbib2,
  author       = {S. F. Edwards},
  year         = 1967,
  title        = {Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I},
  journaltitle = {Proc. Phys. Soc.},
  volume       = {91},
  pages        = {513},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipab730bbib2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punctuation after the year is controlled by `nametitledelim`, the volume can be made bold by changing the `volume` field format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  dashed=false,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{ipab730bbib2,
  author       = {S. F. Edwards},
  year         = 1967,
  title        = {Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I},
  journaltitle = {Proc. Phys. Soc.},
  volume       = {91},
  pages        = {513},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ipab730bbib2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Edwards S F (1967) ‘Statistical Mechanics With Topological Constraints: I’. In: Proc. Phys. Soc. 91, p. 513.]

Comment: It's working fine and i would like to more changes in biblatex. Where can i study this commands?

Comment: @Balaji https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 is a great start, but at some point the best way to learn these things is to look at the source code of the styles directly (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864 and maybe also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542725/35864). But many, many specific questions have also already been answered on this site. It's 'just' a question of guessing the right search terms to find them.